# Bit representation of a C vector

Tags: c, vector, bit, endianness

Working in little endian, which is excatly (including eof if there is) the bit representation of a C vector like this?

```
unsigned char vet[] = {0x0f, 0x05};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit representation of a vector of `unsigned char`s is not dependent on endianness, because `char` types are single-byte, while endianness tells you how multiple bytes are arranged in memory.

Therefore, `0x0f` would be found at an earlier address in memory than `0x05`, producing

```
0000111100000101
```

> including eof if there is [one]

Unlike C strings and arrays initialized with C strings, arrays initialized with curly brace initializers do not have an end mark.

Comment: Ok, so i think that avery two HEX number i've got 8 bit, whatever they are, rigth? So why i've got this exercise were lenght of this vector is given by prof as 18 bit and not 24? unsigned char vet[] = { 0xBC,0xFF,0x01 };

Comment: @caramelleamare I have no idea how to count 18 bits in three bytes, apart from making each character 6-bit. I would definitely ask the prof where the remaining six bits are.

Comment: Infact i asked but i still recived any answer and i don't understand how to procede with the exercise! And nowhere is written to consider char as 6-bit long. The exercise asks me to find min and max subsequence of 0 bit in that given vector.

Comment: @caramelleamare min is 1, max is 7 regardless of how you order the vector (front to back or back to front).

Comment: 7?! Isn't max 5? However still remains mistery about the length.

Comment: @caramelleamare I am talking about your other example, `BC,FF,01`, with seven consecutive zeros in the representation of `0x01`.

Comment: Prof says "If len is minor then a multipe of 8, it means that bits of last byte are not totally used".

Comment: @caramelleamare That wouldn't make `BC,FF,01` count 18, though: it could be 22 if `BC` is the last byte, but that's about it. Chopping off the initial unused bits along with the trailing ones would produce 15.

Comment: Couldn't be `0x01` the last byte represented with bits `01`? So it could be 8+8+2 without chopping.

Comment: @caramelleamare Hex `01` is binary `00000001`, so zeros are in the middle, and cannot be dropped.

Comment: Right, but why you say that `BC` is the last byte and not `01`?

Comment: @caramelleamare I tried it both ways to see if we could "back into" prof's solution by ordering the bytes in some other way, but it does not produce 18 no matter how you order the bytes.

Comment: Ok, i asked him, let's see. Maybe also that the last byte is `01` truncated after the first two bit `00`

Answer (score 0):

Well, so if vector is:

```
unsigned char vet[] = { 0xBC,0xFF,0x01 }
```

Bit representation should be:

```
101111001111111100000001
```

And its length is 24 bit because there is no end mark, rigth?